# Unable to 'pip install Pillow'. It's giving me an error that 'headers or lib files could not be found for jpeg'

Tags: python-imaging-library, python-3.9

I need to install the PIL/Pillow module in python for school, but it keeps giving me an error and I have no idea why (especially since the rest of the class has gotten it to work). My lab instructor can't even help me. Here's the main error I'm getting:

'''The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.'''

The rest of the error is:

'''Collecting Pillow
Using cached Pillow-8.3.2.tar.gz (48.8 MB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for Pillow, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python3.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\jmder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d40m3y5k\pillow_76d63863c38642d3b650f78e6e9b009d\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\jmder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d40m3y5k\pillow_76d63863c38642d3b650f78e6e9b009d\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\jmder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-sm1kcten\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\msys64\mingw64\include\python3.9\Pillow'
cwd: C:\Users\jmder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d40m3y5k\pillow_76d63863c38642d3b650f78e6e9b009d
Complete output (178 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9
creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL_binary.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL_util.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL_version.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL_*init*_.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
copying src\PIL_*main*_.py -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-3.9\PIL
running egg_info
writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
adding license file 'LICENSE' (matched pattern 'LICEN[CS]E*')
reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.c'
warning: no files found matching '*.h'
warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
dllwrap: WARNING: dllwrap is deprecated, use gcc -shared or ld -shared instead

```
The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d40m3y5k\pillow_76d63863c38642d3b650f78e6e9b009d\setup.py", line 976, in <module>
    setup(
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\command\install.py", line 547, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 79, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 341, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Users\jmder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d40m3y5k\pillow_76d63863c38642d3b650f78e6e9b009d\setup.py", line 788, in build_extensions
    raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException: jpeg

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jmder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d40m3y5k\pillow_76d63863c38642d3b650f78e6e9b009d\setup.py", line 1035, in <module>
    raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException:

The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

Please see the install instructions at:
   https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python3.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\jmder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d40m3y5k\pillow_76d63863c38642d3b650f78e6e9b009d\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\jmder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d40m3y5k\pillow_76d63863c38642d3b650f78e6e9b009d\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\jmder\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-sm1kcten\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\msys64\mingw64\include\python3.9\Pillow' Check the logs for full command output.'''

**Running Windows 10, Python 3.9.6**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
python3.9 -m pip install pillow --upgrade
```

This helped me with library issues.

See also: [upgrade pillow suggested, but then already up-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400854/upgrade-pillow-suggested-but-then-already-up-to-date)

Try this for all library problems, which occur. It must be done with same user and environment like the executed script. Consider to install libraries only as root/admin or use a clean environment.

Edit: The problem is, if a library is installed in different environment, it's probably found by pip, but not by your python interpreter. "--upgrade" reinstalls a library no matter if it's already installed or not.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

try to add --trusted-host:

```
python3.9 -m pip install pillow --upgrade -i http://pypi.douban.com/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.douban.com
```

it solved my problem